# app-engine iOS push notification project not sending notifications

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using the [Google Sample project to setup push notification on my app-engine backend](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-ios-push-notification-sample-backend-java). I believe that I have followed the project to the letter, but my notifications are still not being delivered to iOS. I am tracking everything on app-engine and I see that the task queue supposedly sends my notifications. But my iPhone is not receiving them. Also I already checked that I am registering the correct deviceToken on my server. So now I am thinking that something about the project itself is not right. To double check that my iPhone is fine, I try sending with Urban Airship and it works. I Cannot afford the kind of pricing that Urban Airship has put in place (e.g. $200/month for 0-10k users). So I need to get this library to work.

Will someone else please verify that the project from Google actually works? And if it does not (of course it does not), how do you fix it to get it to work?

Comment: maybe this framework it's using the old SSL 3.0 for sending notifications... from Oct 29 2014 it is mandatory to use TLS for that... https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10222014a

Comment: @TonyMkenu you may be right. I don't understand enough to go change the Google Library that I am linking to. Do you know of another free alternative? Urban Airship is out of my price range and I don't know enough about the other services out there (i.e. I don't want to pay for something that may be crappy).

Comment: Or better yet: Is someone here knowledgeable enough to fork the Google project, update it and share with the rest of us mortals?

Comment: @TonyMkenu actually, looking back at your comment, I don't think that's the problem. The certificate is generated by iOS itself, yes? So how would that be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Since it sounds like you are open to alternatives, give [Heroku](https://addons.heroku.com/zeropush) a try.  Their product ZeroPush gives you a significant number of free push notifications (5000 pushes, 100 devices).

If you want to maintain your existing App Engine stack, you can build your push notification stack on Heroku (which can be nothing more than a dumb ZeroPush endpoint that sends push notifications), and use it like a remote web service from your App Engine app.

Comment: At this point I would really rather roll out my own (or get Google's to work). I don't want such funny business as what Urban Airship is pulling. Urban Airship used to be a lot cheaper than this (1 million free push); they changed their pricing without notice. So I want to avoid those pay-for-push systems if I can.

Comment: Fair enough.  I would like to point out though that any server costs you are likely to incur by rolling out your own, are likely to exceed "free" (both in terms of out of pocket monetary cost, and opportunity cost for your time in troubleshooting problems like this).  Using an easy out-of-the-box solution like this alleviates that for the short term, allowing you to launch more quickly and reduce cost associated with the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not stick to java , just giva a [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/) a try

Comment: My server is built with Java